# Script works on my server but not live server. DB settings etc correct, same PHP version

Tags: php, mysql, file

Heres my script;

Basically it works on my server but not on the live server i'm trying to put it on. Here are the php infos for both servers.

When I say it doesn't work, it doesn't seem the be pasrsing the file. I'm trying to see if theres any glaringly obvious errors i've made in the code I can't see!

http://cdev.skinzy.org/ip/phpinfo.php <- works on this server
http://robottraffic.net/ip/phpinfo.php <- not on this server

What's wrong in the code? ($fileurl is set in the config)

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$lines = file($fileurl);

$dateTime = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
print_r($lines);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if(preg_match("/<br>\d/", $line)) {
        $output = substr($line, 4);

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `list_of_ips` WHERE `IP` LIKE '%$output%'");

        IF (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0){
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM `list_of_ips` WHERE `IP` LIKE '%$output%' LIMIT 1");
        }

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO list_of_ips (ID, IP, DateTime) VALUES('', '$output', '$dateTime') ") or die(mysql_error());

        echo $output;
        echo "<br />";
        } 
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: None at all, it's strange. I thought it could be the php execution time but when I tested with a local file it took a couple of secs but distill didn't work

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); to the top of your php file, you will get all errors (if any) then. I see in the second php info, display errors is 'off', set it to 'on' with the ini_set option (http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php)

Comment: Still no errors! It's something in the foreach as Nothing is being echo'd out, even when i do echo("test"); after the } after the <br />

Comment: "Doesn't work" >.< _What_ doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the script doesn't parse the file or add to the database

Comment: If nothing is shown, there is something wrong with the execution of your script. Maybe you don't have enough rights to set the display_errors mode on the server, with the ini_set function. Besides, maybe you don't have any permissions to open the file, so it doesn't open it and gives you a blank page.

Comment: Would that be the same for remotely opening a URL? Potential permissions problem?

Comment: Open remote files, even need more permissions than opening a local file

Answer (score 1):

One weird thing, not necessarily the reason of your problem, is that file_get_contents() returns string and not an array, so you can't traverse it with foreach. You probably wanted to use file().

Comment: Sorry, you're right, that's a relic from my testing to try and debug, it's normally file!